# Besides F1, F2, F3, (Ctrl + Fs and so on), which are good (available) keys to create custom commands on Vim?

Tags: vim, command, key

Besides <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fs</kbd> and so on), which are good (available) keys to create custom commands on Vim?

Some plugins use <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>\</kbd>. For instance, `\be` and `,cc`. Which are other good available keys to create custom commands on Vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a fan of using `<Leader>` in all my custom maps.  That way I can easily avoid stomping on default mappings, and I can quickly change my `mapleader` whenever I want/need to.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I have remapped my 
`CAPSLOCK` as `CTRL`

and for vim

`imap jk <ESC>`

The last trick has helped me a lot. I dont have to lift my fingers to get out from `normal mode` to `insert mode`.

And it works both ways, `jk` in `normal mode` is an innocent combination - `move down one, move up one`. So by remapping `jk` as `ESC` you're not losing out anything.

Comment: Seriously? How do you type stuff like `Dijkstra`?

Comment: if by `Dijkstra` you mean `D(Delete)i(Insert)jk(Escape)s(substitute)tr(find r)a(append)` Yes. I dont have to lift my hand for escape key. Ever.

Comment: No, I meant the literal text `Dijkstra`, in insert mode. I tried your suggested `imap` command and `jk` actually exits insert mode as expected. So typing `Dijkstra` in insert mode ends up inserting `Dtra` because `jk` exits insert mode and `s` deletes the `i` and reenters insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

Since the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key is the most used key in vim it beneficial to have it mapped somewhere else.

I've seen others used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>jj</kbd>, <kbd>;;</kbd> and  for a secondary <kbd>ESC</kbd> key

```
imap  jj  <ESC>
imap  ;;  <ESC>
```

Comment: I'm a fan of making CAPSLOCK be ESC